# How to create a new user in AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new user with AWS APIs for Java, but i can't figure out what i need to do.

So far i managed to write this code that gives me a CreateUserRequest, a CreateAccessKeyRequest and a BasicAWSCredentials with all the fields filled.

I just can't figure out what to do next. Do I have to use CreateUserResult? How?

```
    CreateUserRequest user = new CreateUserRequest("userName");

    CreateAccessKeyRequest key = new CreateAccessKeyRequest();

    BasicAWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("access", "secret");

    key.withUserName(user.getUserName());
    key.setRequestCredentials(cred);

    user.setRequestCredentials(key.getRequestCredentials());
    user.setPath("/");
```

EDIT: I'm still working on this today.

I think I need to use the createUser(CreateUserRequest) method of AmazonIdentityManagementClient class. (which returns a CreateUserResult, I was not supposed to instantiate this class manually)

Problem is, I don't know how to properly initialize this class with the right AWSCredentials (I'm using the account's AccessKey and SecretAccessKey).

Comment: did you solve the problem??the accepted answer is not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CreateUserRequest user = new CreateUserRequest("userName");

CreateAccessKeyRequest key = new CreateAccessKeyRequest();

BasicAWSCredentials cred = new BasicAWSCredentials("access", "secret");

key.withUserName(user.getUserName());
key.setRequestCredentials(cred);

user.setRequestCredentials(key.getRequestCredentials());
user.setPath("/");
AmazonIdentityManagementClient client =  new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(cred);
CreateUserResult result = client.createUser(user);
```

Comment: I was trying something like this, but I keep getting this error with the credentials I put in. (I tried also to use a 20-chars accessKey and a 40-chars secretKey, but nothing changed)

Status Code: 403, AWS Service: AmazonIdentityManagement, AWS Request ID: f15e9c40-0e09-11e2-a5c4-871c4c40223d, AWS Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId, AWS Error Message: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Am I not supposed to use the main account credentials to create users?

Comment: @EugenioLaghi You can use the main account credentials, but it isn't recommended. But that's not the issue. The issue is that your token is invalid. Can you check under your security credentials if you really are using correct ones? And is your account allowed to create users?

Comment: I'm just testing the AWS for a future use in my company, so I can mess around with the main account, just to let you know about my situation. :)
Anyway, I copypasted the account's credentials in a .properties file that I am using in tests with other services, so I'm confident they are correct. Dunno, I'm gonna try again with one of my admin users..

Comment: Ok, now I'm sure I'm using the right credentials for the AmazonIdentityManagementClient: I created a new AccessKey for my Admin User via Java.
The problem may be with the credentials I'm trying to assign to the new user, I'm gonna work on those.

Comment: Hi! Although this code works, the method setRequestCredentials() is showing as deprecated. Is there a newer version for this implementation available?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can help you :

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUser.html

I've not played with Amazon S3 service, but with another service like it and I had to create the Request manually and sign the request with correct data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I already went through most of these pages looking for informations, they're full of gaps also in the important parts...