# Does AWS SDK for Android supports IAM new user creation?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a new user in IAM using Amazon web-service SDK for Android.

But after searching a lot I couldn't find any sample codes or documentation clearly stating the above functionality. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711975/how-to-create-a-new-user-in-aws?rq=1) and also [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324869/aws-iam-create-new-user-returning-html-instead-of-xml-response-android)

The first link only works for Java SDK only.

So my question is does AWS SDK for Android support a way to create a new IAM user programatically?

Comment: Can you explain why do you need to create IAM user by ab Android mobile?

Comment: It is for future use...suppose 3 users are registers in IAM and if they want to share pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem.I mailed AWS technical support team for solution.They clearly stated that **android sdk for aws does not supports the new user creation for IAM.**

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not sure about IAM implementation for Android, as a Web Service you can use them in a deeper level anyway, but I don't think this is your needs.

I suggest you read [IAM Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/LimitationsOnEntities.html), which shows some limitation on users number, which may be a problem for future growth.
In your scenario I would suggest [this article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/Android/4611615499399490) which will require another layer to control user authentications with token control, it will solve user limitations, will give you a lot more security and control over your system.
After all, you can still using IAM for user's power level control, as another security layer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.But my client want me to create IAM account programatically.